# Children won't translate along with parent in CSS3 transformation

Tags: css, css-transforms

In order to translate an element completely out of view, I used `transform: translate(0, -100%);`. Its children however, if you resize the window compressing its height far enough, will gradually reappear. I have no clue why they do this, and I'd like someone to shed light on the reason why this happens. Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ruzhx41/6/).

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
         <div id="circle1"></div>
         <div id="circle2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#background {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
}

#circle1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}

#circle2 {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have fixed heights for your cirecles (500px / 400px). When `#background`'s height becomes less than that by resizing the window, the circles would overflow `#background` vertically. 
The `translate`movement by 100% refers to `#background`, so you still see the part of the circles that would overflow `#background` without the `translate` setting.

Comment: Thank you. But I already tried using `overflow: hidden` and it didn't work.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` will only hide stuff *inside* `background`, i.e. stuff that overfolws the actual borders of `background`.  The moved circles are partly *inside* those borders...